# Resty-GWT dynamic code generation

Tags: rest, gwt, dynamic, resty-gwt

I am using the resty-gwt library and wondering if it would be possible to use the JsonEncoderDecoder interface dynamically?

eg. I have a pojo as follows:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")
 public class MyObject {....}
```

With the class name returned in the response: is it possible using generators to generate the interface

```
public interface MyObjectCodec extends JsonEncoderDecoder<MyObject > {}
```

and somehow make a call to GWT.create(MyObjectCodec.class)
so that I can decode the object?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can even if I have never tried.

Extract from restyGWT.gwt.xml

```
  <generate-with class="org.fusesource.restygwt.rebind.RestServiceGenerator">
    <when-type-assignable class="org.fusesource.restygwt.client.RestService" />
  </generate-with>
  <generate-with class="org.fusesource.restygwt.rebind.JsonEncoderDecoderGenerator">
    <when-type-assignable class="org.fusesource.restygwt.client.JsonEncoderDecoder" />
  </generate-with>
  <generate-with class="org.fusesource.restygwt.rebind.DirectRestServiceGenerator">
    <when-type-assignable class="org.fusesource.restygwt.client.DirectRestService" />
  </generate-with>
```

So if you are writing a JsonEncoderDecoder the generator should generate the code for you.

You should be able to use the method `JSONValue encode(T value)` to encode your object in JSONValue

I do not know what you mean by dynamic but IMO it is all "static" meaning it does not really depends on runtime variables or anything.